How do i add a bunch of numbers to a total?
OK so i have this code that counts the number of times a certain phrase is repeated in a folder full of text files but i'm trying to figure out how to display a total after echoing all of them
set /p player=enter player name: 

if /i "%player%"=="Colinderr" (
    for %%i in (*.log) do (
        find /c "Colinderr was killed" %%i
    )
    echo /a deathcount
) else if /i "%player%"=="QuickCrash1" (
    for %%i in (*.log) do (
        find /c "QuickCrash1 was killed" %%i
    )
)
pause


Capture the counter with another for /f loop and add them up with set /a.
Another for around spares you repeating code segments (easily to expand for more players).
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%p in ("Colinderr","QuickCrash1") do (
   set "sum=0"
   for %%i in (*.log) do (
      for /f %%j in ('type "%%i"^|find /c "%%p was killed"') do (
        echo %%~ni: %%j
        set /a sum+=%%j
      )
    )
    echo total deathcount %%p: !sum!
    echo/
)

